# What is the point of a navigation toolbar in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can someone explain why/when I should use a navigation toolbar instead of just having custom objects in each custom view?  What is the main benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a [`UINBavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is used to navigate to different screens.

> A navigation controller object manages the currently displayed screens using the **navigation stack**.

Comment: Ok.  SO the toolbar should be an extension if modifying the stack beyond the top navigation controls?